# How to get list with conditional in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want select only rows have columns `is_Deleted = 0` to show.
I have a function in `core/MY_Model.php` like this:

```
function get_list_where($table, $input = array())
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where($this->$table, $this->$input);
}
```

In the `controller/news/News.php` at function index:

```
function index(){
    $data_where=array(
        'is_deleted'         => '0'
    );
    $this->data['listNews'] = $this->Mnews->get_list_where('tl_News', $data_where);
}
```

In this: `Mnews` I define in Model like this:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Mslidenews extends MY_Model{
        var $table = "tl_news";
    }
?>
```

My table with name: `tl_news`.

Normal, I will show to datatable like:

```
$input['order'] = array('id','DESC');
$this->data['listNew'] = $this->Mnew->get_list($input);
```

With function get_list($input) like this:

```
function get_list($input = array())
{
    $this->get_list_set_input($input);
    if(isset($input['join'])){
        $this->db_default->from($this->table);
        foreach($input['join'] as $table){
            $this->db_default->join($table,$this->table.".{$table}_id = {$table}.{$table}_id",'left');
        }
        $query = $this->db_default->get();
    }else{
        $query = $this->db_default->get($this->table);
    }
    return $query->result();
}
```

Updated: I fixed my problem.

In function `get_list_set_input()` I created like this:

```
protected function get_list_set_input($input = array())
{
    if ((isset($input['where'])) && $input['where'])
    {
        $this->db->where($input['where']);
    }

    if ((isset($input['like'])) && $input['like'])
    {
        $this->db->like($input['like'][0], $input['like'][1]); 
    }

    if (isset($input['order'][0]) && isset($input['order'][1]))
    {
        $this->db->order_by($input['order'][0], $input['order'][1]);
    }
    else
    {
        $order = ($this->order == '') ? array($this->table.'.'.$this->key, 'desc') : $this->order;
        $this->db->order_by($order[0], $order[1]);
    }

    if (isset($input['limit'][0]) && isset($input['limit'][1]))
    {
        $this->db->limit($input['limit'][0], $input['limit'][1]);
    }

}
```

And from `controller/news/News.php` I changed to:

```
$input['where']=array('is_deleted' => '1');
$this->data['listNews'] = $this->Mnews->get_list($input);
```

It's working for me.
Thanks all.